# How do I write setters and getters for an array? (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, setter, getter, getter-setter

Im writing a class within c++, however I am not certain on how to create the setters and getters for the arrays (sorry for it being a basic question!) I am getting the following error:

expected primary expression before ']' token

Here is my code:

```
Class planet: public body
{
private:
  string name[];
  string star[];
public:
  void nameSetter (string h_name[])
  {
      name[] = h_name[];
  }
};
```

Once again I am sorry for such I silly question, I know I am not passing an index through, however, when I create an index it throws up a large amount of errors!

Comment: Do you want each instance of planet to have 1 name and 1 star? If so you dont need arrays of strings which is what your declaration of name and star are implying you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string name[];
```

This is not an array, it is a pointer. Use `vectors` instead:

```
#include <vector>
class planet: public body
{
private:
  vector<string> name;
  vector<string> star;
public:
  void nameSetter (const vector<string> &h_name)
  {
      name = h_name;
  }
};
```

Comment: When I use this method, it says the following error:

incompatible types in assignment of 'const std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >' to 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >[0]'

On the line that states name = h_name;

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: oh yeah, [it is](http://ideone.com/toq2ok). Also look at the famous `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Comment: @DamienRenner: [This code compiles](http://ideone.com/vknML1), so the error must come from other part of the code that you didn't show.

Comment: @ybungalobill: `-pedantic-errors` if you want GCC to enforce the standard.  And yes, in a function argument, it is a pointer, but that's different.  In a function argument, you can even provide a size, and it's still a pointer.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: perhaps you are right. Still applies here for the argument, and `extern string name[];` is still legal as a declaration of a static-storage.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in C++ have compile-time fixed sizes. You can't have a declaration like `string name[];` because it leaves the size empty. You can't do that unless you provide an initialization list from which the size is determined.

In addition, array type arguments are transformed to pointer arguments. So your `string h_name[]` argument is actually a `string* h_name`.

```
name[] = h_name[];
```

This line doesn't make much sense. It's almost like you're trying to access elements of `name` and `h_name` without giving an index. Perhaps you were intending to assign the `h_name` array to the `name` array, like so:

```
name = h_name;
```

However, as we've just seen, `h_name` is actually a pointer. And in fact, you can't assign to an array anyway, so even if `h_name` were an array, this still wouldn't work.

You'll be much better off using a standard container like `std::vector`. It appears that you want dynamically sized arrays anyway, so this will make that easy.

Answer (score 0):

Even though an answer has been selected, I think maybe the original question may have been misunderstood.

I think what the OP intended was that each instance of planet should have 1 name and 1 star; so the array notation he's used in his code is a misunderstanding on his part about arrays and strings. Based on this assumption I will continue.

When you declare

```
string name[];
```

I believe you just want to hold the name of 1 planet, in which case you don't need and array, you just need a single string. 
ie

```
string name;
```

The same goes for star.

This would make the code

```
Class planet: public body
{
private:
  string name;
  string star;
public:
  void nameSetter (const string& h_name)
  {
      name = h_name;
  }
};
```